# Creating and using an IRP internally within a driver

Tags: windows-7, driver, device-driver, kernel

I am writing a driver which currently handles IRPs send from userland.

My question is: is there any way to construct IRPs inside the driver and pass them internally to the functions currently handling userland IRPs?

I've seen information about creating IRPs and sending them to *other* drivers, but I need to pass them *internally*.

Greatly appreciate any help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the best way is, but I'd see if it's possible to just allocate an IRP and either send it using IoCallDriver() or pass it directly to the dispatch routine. Also, I think you should be able to use functions like NtDeviceIoControl()/ZwDeviceIoControl(), which would be largely equivalent to calling the driver from the user mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I'm now doing is the following: http://pastebin.com/xAKBYuTi

Sadly I get a BSOD (http://i.imgur.com/Uo0iu.png) when I try to create the IRP.

Commenting it out makes it run fine. Am I missing something? Have I got the right idea with sending the IRP and deviceobject to my IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (NPF_IoCOntrol) function?

Very grateful,

Comment: @GBC: I can't say what exactly is wrong, but per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) not every parameter is optional, yet Event and IoStatusBlock seem to be set to NULL. Also, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that it's an access violation, meaning that some pointer is wrong (or maybe points to paged memory). I'd run the driver on a machine to which you connect with the kernel debugger (WinDbg) from another PC and inspect the exception record to see where the memory access fails and why.